# Express req.body is empty in form submission

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following form and submitting it results in an empty `req.body` This is my HTML:

```
<form action="/contact" name="contactUs" id="contactUs" method="POST">
   <label for="email">Email Message</label>
   <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
  <input type="submit" value='Save'>
</form>
```

And this is (part) of my `server.js`:

```
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use("/", expressStaticGzip("dist"));

app.post("/contact", (req, res) => {
  console.log('anyone there?')
  res.json(req.body);
});
```

The `console.log` works fine. I get an empty object for `req.body` though.

Comment: Your input tags are not closed `/>`.

Comment: @chsdk — They is no suggestion in the question that they are using XHTML, so the elements are closed.

Comment: @Quentin Well it's a bad practice, we should mention it.

Comment: @chsdk — It is not bad practice. Bloating HTML with optional features designed to make it compatible with XML is pointless and a waste of bytes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're submitting as HTML POST that means you are using `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

This means that you need to add `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))`
, This way express can parse that request and put it to `req.body`

Comment: thanks bruce. much appreciated

Comment: As per your form data if you have simple text/number/email/password fields, I found my `req.body` getting populated as soon as I explicitly mentioned `enctype="text/html"` in my submit form.

Comment: still help till date. thank you